# Moving Files based on filename

Tags: powershell

Im looking to move files based on the last half of the filename. Files look like this

```
43145123_Stuff.zip

14353135_Stuff.zip

2t53542y_Stuff.zip

422yg3hh_things.zip
```

I am only looking to move files that end in Stuff.zip
I have this in PowerShell so far but it only will move files according to the first half of a file name.

```
#set Source and Destination folder location

$srcpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Source"

$dstpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Destination"

#Set the files name which need to move to destination folder

$filterLists = @("stuff.txt","things")

 
#Get all the child file list with source folder

$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpath -Force -Recurse

#loop the source folder files to find the match

foreach ($file in $fileList)

{

#checking the match with filterlist

foreach($filelist in $filterLists)

{

#$key = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,8)

#Spliting value before "-" for matching with filterlists value

$splitFileName = $file.BaseName.Substring(0, $file.BaseName.IndexOf('-'))

 
if ($splitFileName -in $filelist)


{


$fileName = $file.Name

 
Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstpath

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some differences between the state goal and what the code actually does. This will move the files to the destination directory. When you are confident that the files will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

```
$srcpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Source"
$dstpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Destination"
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $srcpath |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '.*Stuff.zip$') {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dstpath -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Comment: This has been super helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Nick, if an answer has been helpful, you can upvote it with the triangle pointed up. When you identify the best answer, select the check mark. These are the ways to let other SO users know what worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be written in PowerShell very efficiently (I hope I got the details right, let me know):

```
Get-ChildItem $srcpath -File -Force -Recurse | 
  where { ($_.Name -split "_" | select -last 1) -in $filterLists } |
  Move-Item $dstpath
```

Alternatively, if you *only* want to look for this one particular filter, you can specify that directly, using wildcards:

```
Get-ChildItem $srcpath -Filter "*_Stuff.zip"
```

Comment: This has been super helpful, thank you!

Comment: Forgive my question 
Do you mean this 

$srcpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Source"
$dstpath = "C:\Powershelltest\Destination"
Get-ChildItem $srcpath -File -Force -Recurse | 
  where { ($_.Name -split "  ") -in $filterLists } |
  Move-Item $dstpath

Comment: will it create sub folders in destination folder, or they should be present

Comment: @m26348762 `Move-Item` will not create folders. It will throw if the destination directory does not exist. If you specify a non-existant path, it will try to use it as a file name. You should have a closer look at the documentation for the details.